# How Validate input as only character and can have space between in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to have a method that validate the input to make sure it is only character I also allow white space like, "Alton Drive" the code I have is only allow character no white space.

```
 public bool IsCorrectString(string val)
    {
     foreach (char c in val)
      {
       if (!char.IsLetter(c))
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

I am not sure if regex is better to use here or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex will certainly be much simpler.

```
^[A-Za-z\s]*$
```

This regex will match letters and whitespace only, and will fail for a string that contains anything else.

You'll want to use [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) for this.

For example:

```
public bool IsCorrectString(string val)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(val, @"^[A-Za-z\s]*$")
}
```

Comment: -1: Your letters are only the same as the OP's letters if the input is English...

Comment: @280Z28 I didn't see anything to indicate that would be a problem.

Comment: I believe the expression you want is `^[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\s]*$`

Comment: I actually think the LINQ version is equally simple (simpler if you're using that expression in the comments, who the hell would know what that is?) and it definitely performs better.

Comment: which one is more readable ? `LINQ` or `Regex` ? and also,this doesn't work if there is space in the start or end.it still return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Boolean HasSpecialChars(string yourString)
    {
        return yourString.Any(ch => !Char.IsLetter(ch) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just augment your if statement from; `if (!char.IsLetter(c))` to `if (!char.IsLetter(c) || c != ' ')` to solve the problem. You could also use RegEx, the code would be cleaner but the performance would be worse. Your code could also be cleaned up and I personally think that would be the best choice (use iteration but have cleaner code). Here's my clean 1 line version with LINQ;

```
  return val.Where(c => !char.IsLetter(c) || !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: You don't need `ToCharArray`.string is already  an `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: @Selman22 thank you, I was unsure so I just put it there for safety (of course I'm writing my code on the SO page so no way to check to confirm it was unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public bool IsCorrectString(string val)
{
    foreach (char c in val)
    {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && !char.IsLetter(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or shorter:

```
return val.All(c => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || Char.IsLetter(c));
```

Note that it also includes other characters like tabs or newlines. If that's not desired use  (space).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `LINQ` in one statement:

```
public bool IsCorrectString(string val)
{
    return val.All(x => char.IsLetter(x) || char.IsWhiteSpace(x));
}
```

If you want to allow space only between two words then you can also use `Split` like this:

```
public bool IsCorrectString(string val)
{
    return val.Split().All(x => x.All(char.IsLetter) && x != string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition:

```
if (!char.IsLetter(c) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) {
    return false;
}
```